# Run sql server job from .net code

Tags: c#

I am trying to run a sql job from a windows service, according to the [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms202348.aspx) and this
[A blog post](http://blog.the-dargans.co.uk/2007/02/executing-job-on-sql-2005-server-in-c.html) I need to run the job by declaring a ***JOB STEP NAME***. Is there a way to 
tell the job to ***START AT STEP 1*** , this way if the step names change I dont need to change a config file every time?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [sp_start_job](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186757%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) system stored proc.  The step name is optional.  Just execute it as you would any other stored proc.